# Openbox: disable entire keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, xorg, openbox

I'm running Ubuntu Server (16.04.3 LTS) with X, Openbox and Chromium in kioskmode on a touchscreen device. It is starting up as a (non-root) user straight into the kiosk.

There is no need for a mouse or keyboard, so I'm starting X with

```
startx -- -nocursor
```

what effectively disables the mouse. But the user still can plug in a keyboard and do all sorts of unwanted things with Chromium. So I'm looking for ways to **disable the entire keyboard**.

To catch and disable every single key and key combination in Openbox `rc.xml` seems an impossible task to me. So is there some switch with startx or Openbox to disable the keyboard? (I've tried `-nokeyboard` but it gives an error. Also `-keyboard null` doesn't work.)

Or, as a last resort, is there a way to disable keyboard (and mouse) at user login?

Answer (score 2):

`xinput` is your tool.

Find id of your keyboard with `xinput --list`. Possible output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ HP Webcam                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Get id of `AT Translated ... keyboard`. In this case it is `10`.
Disable keyboard input with:

```
xinput --disable 10
```

As one-liner:

```
xinput --disable $(xinput list | grep "AT Translated"  | cut -f2 | cut -d= -f2)
```

(You can do the same with mouse or touchpad, just use matching id).

P.S.: I am not sure if the keyboard entry is visible as long as no keyboard is plugged in, or if an additional one appears after plugging one in. I have no hardware to check that right now. Maybe you have to create an `udev` rule that watches for new keyboards and runs `xinput --disable [...]`.